# Ajax get new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

there is a script what can run loaded javascript again?

My problem is when I load page by Ajax(jquery). And i load page to body. Content what was loaded is ok, but javascript dont run again.

Example: Page -> click button -> reload body content -> content is datatable and nothing more (javascript stay).

Is there any solutions for this problem ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you will need to run your scripts again once the DOM has been updated.

Comment: You can use the success callback function of jQuery.ajax to execute your JavaScript function again.

Comment: if you put them all in another function you can easily recall them when ever you need them.

Comment: Did you check for a javascript error after everything loaded? I'm curious if javascript isn't running any longer because it hit an error.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but the template have lots of script and do backcall for all will be suicide. :D

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723471/how-to-run-scripts-loaded-dynamically-with-javascript, phtrivier's answer in particular.